# Append HTML file contents to div - Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

Is it possible to `appendChild(index.html)` ?

I know it's possible to do this:

```
fetch(`${htmlFile}`)
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.text();
    }
  })
  .then((htmlSnippet) => {
    targetElement.innerHTML = htmlSnippet;
  });
```

But for some reason, the changed HTML of `targetElement` doesn't react to any of my other javascript functions.

Comment: Your code with `innerHTML` isn't *appending*, it's *replacing*. If you want to append, use `targetElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", htmlSnippet);` or similar, which will avoid destroying all of the elements in `targetElement` and thus won't disconnect any event handlers you have on them. See the linked question's answers. (BTW: You need to handle the possibility your first `then` callback implicitly returns `undefined`. At the moment you're using that `undefined` as though it were HTML text in your second `then` callback.)

Comment: (But no, there's no method to directly append a URL's contents to an element. Instead, `fetch` and things like `insertAdjacentHTML` are provided so you can do it.)

Comment: Well, that works, but the appended HTML still doesnt react to any of my other javascript.

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements). If you used delegated event handling, they would; if you don't, you have to include code to attach handlers to the new elements.